# Brainfuck with C# operator overloading

Tags: c#, brainfuck

I overloaded some C# operators to get a pseudo version of the Brainfuck symbols in the effort of understanding the flow of this language.

I got this version:

```
void Main()
{
    /*
    *   Write `Hello World!`
    *           using operators overloading for brainfuck symbols
    */
    var _ = new brainfuck();


    _ = + + + + +    + + + + +     _        ; // set cell #0 to 10

    while (_)
    {
        _ =     + + + + +    + +       (_ > 1)              ; // add 7 to #1
        _ =     + + + + +    + + + + + (_ > 1)              ; // add 10 to #2
        _ =     + + +                  (_ > 1)              ; // add 3 to #3
        _ =     +                      (_ > 1)              ; // add 1 to #4

        _ =     -                      (_ < 1 < 1 < 1 < 1)  ; // decrement 0
    }
    _ =     ~   + +                    (_ > 1)              ; // write 'H'
    _ =     ~   +                      (_ > 1)              ; // write 'e'
    _ =     ~   + + + + +    + +        _                   ; //write 'l'
    _ =     ~                           _                   ; //write 'l'
    _ =     ~   + + +                   _                   ; // write 'o'
    _ =     ~   + +                     (_ > 1)             ; // write ' '
    _ =     ~   + + + + +    + + + + +   + + + + +      (_ < 1 < 1)     ; // write 'W'
    _ =     ~                           (_ > 1)             ; // write 'o'
    _ =     ~   + + +                   _               ; // write 'r'
    _ =     ~   - - - - -    -          _               ; // write 'l'
    _ =     ~   - - - - -    - - -      _               ; // write 'd'
    _ =     ~   +                       (_ > 1)         ; // write '!'
    _ =     ~                           (_ > 1)         ; // write '\n'
}
public class brainfuck
{
    private List<int> cells;
    private int currentCell;
    public brainfuck()
    {
        cells = new List<int>{0};
    }

    public static brainfuck operator + (brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.plus();
        return bf;
    }
    public static brainfuck operator - (brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.minus();
        return bf;
    }
    public static brainfuck operator > (brainfuck bf, int pos = 1) 
    {
        bf.right();
        return bf;
    }
    public static brainfuck operator < (brainfuck bf, int pos = 1) 
    {
        bf.left();
        return bf;
    }


    public static brainfuck operator ~ (brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.write();
        return bf;
    }
    public static brainfuck operator ! (brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.read();
        return bf;
    }
    public static implicit operator bool (brainfuck bf) 
    {
        return bf.has_data();
    }

    private int plus()
    {
        return ++cells[currentCell];
    }
    private int minus()
    {
        return --cells[currentCell];        
    }
    private void right()
    {
        if (currentCell + 1 == cells.Count)
            cells.Add(0);
        currentCell++;
    }
    private void left()
    {
        if (currentCell > 0)
            currentCell--;
    }
    private int current()
    {
        return cells[currentCell];
    }
    private void write()
    {
        Console.Write((char)current());
    }
    private void read()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int value = Int32.TryParse(input, out value) ? value : 0;
        current(value);
    }
    private bool has_data()
    {
        return current() > 0;
    }
    private void current(int value)
    {
        cells[currentCell] = value;
    }




    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(",",cells);
    }
}
```

I had to cheat with the `[]` command pair using the `while` statement and the flow is very odd from the point of Brainfuck reader, since the `<,>` commands are before the `+,-` in the original *Hello World!* example, and with C# program are in the opposite way.

Do you think I can get a closer version to Brainfuck than the current one?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* get *slightly* closer with the `[]` command pair.

It's actually quite trivial:

Add an indexer to your `brainfuck` class (`public void this[Action bf]`) and put your `while` loop in there.

The indexer would look like:

```
public brainfuck this[Action action]
{
    get
    {
        while (this)
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

You would call it as:

```
_ = _[() => {
    _ =     + + + + +    + +       (_ > 1)              ; // add 7 to #1
    _ =     + + + + +    + + + + + (_ > 1)              ; // add 10 to #2
    _ =     + + +                  (_ > 1)              ; // add 3 to #3
    _ =     +                      (_ > 1)              ; // add 1 to #4

    _ =     -                      (_ < 1 < 1 < 1 < 1)  ; // decrement 0
}];
```

Is it a pain in the rear to use? Yes. Is it in the Brainfuck spirit? Yes.

It's still not *true* brainfuck syntax, but you won't get there with C#.

---

After that, you have a real mess here that needs cleaned.

First: capitalization. In C# we `PascalCase` public members and types (and all methods), and `camelCase` private and local members and types.

```
public class Brainfuck
private bool HasData()
```

Since "Brainfuck" is one word, the "F" in "fuck" is not capitalized.

The optional argument defaults in `operator >` and `operator <` are not at all going to work, remove them.

```
public static brainfuck operator > (brainfuck bf, int pos) 
{
    bf.right();
    return bf;
}
public static brainfuck operator < (brainfuck bf, int pos) 
{
    bf.left();
    return bf;
}
```

Always use braces, even when you don't need them.

```
private void Right()
{
    if (currentCell + 1 == cells.Count)
    {
        cells.Add(0);
    }

    currentCell++;
}
```

Use `int` instead of `Int32` everywhere.

```
int value = int.TryParse(input, out value) ? value : 0;
```

Once we apply all these changes, fix some spacing, we end up with a not-so-bad looking class:

```
public class Brainfuck
{
    private List<int> cells;
    private int currentCell;

    public Brainfuck()
    {
        cells = new List<int>{0};
    }

    public Brainfuck this[Action action]
    {
        get
        {
            while (this)
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }

            return this;
        }
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator + (Brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.Plus();
        return bf;
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator - (Brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.Minus();
        return bf;
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator > (Brainfuck bf, int pos) 
    {
        bf.Right();
        return bf;
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator < (Brainfuck bf, int pos) 
    {
        bf.Left();
        return bf;
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator ~ (Brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.Write();
        return bf;
    }

    public static Brainfuck operator ! (Brainfuck bf) 
    {
        bf.Read();
        return bf;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool (Brainfuck bf) 
    {
        return bf.HasData();
    }

    private int Plus()
    {
        return ++cells[currentCell];
    }

    private int Minus()
    {
        return --cells[currentCell];        
    }

    private void Right()
    {
        if (currentCell + 1 == cells.Count)
        {
            cells.Add(0);
        }

        currentCell++;
    }

    private void Left()
    {
        if (currentCell > 0)
        {
            currentCell--;
        }
    }

    private int Current()
    {
        return cells[currentCell];
    }

    private void Write()
    {
        Console.Write((char)Current());
    }

    private void Read()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int value = int.TryParse(input, out value) ? value : 0;
        Current(value);
    }

    private bool HasData()
    {
        return Current() > 0;
    }

    private void Current(int value)
    {
        cells[currentCell] = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(",",cells);
    }
}
```

And our code for the "Hello World" looks like:

```
void Main()
{
    /*
    *   Write `Hello World!`
    *           using operators overloading for brainfuck symbols
    */
    var _ = new Brainfuck();

    _ = + + + + +    + + + + +     _        ; // set cell #0 to 10

    _ = _[() => {
        _ =     + + + + +    + +       (_ > 1)              ; // add 7 to #1
        _ =     + + + + +    + + + + + (_ > 1)              ; // add 10 to #2
        _ =     + + +                  (_ > 1)              ; // add 3 to #3
        _ =     +                      (_ > 1)              ; // add 1 to #4

        _ =     -                      (_ < 1 < 1 < 1 < 1)  ; // decrement 0
    }];
    _ =     ~   + +                    (_ > 1)              ; // write 'H'
    _ =     ~   +                      (_ > 1)              ; // write 'e'
    _ =     ~   + + + + +    + +        _                   ; //write 'l'
    _ =     ~                           _                   ; //write 'l'
    _ =     ~   + + +                   _                   ; // write 'o'
    _ =     ~   + +                     (_ > 1)             ; // write ' '
    _ =     ~   + + + + +    + + + + +   + + + + +      (_ < 1 < 1)     ; // write 'W'
    _ =     ~                           (_ > 1)             ; // write 'o'
    _ =     ~   + + +                   _               ; // write 'r'
    _ =     ~   - - - - -    -          _               ; // write 'l'
    _ =     ~   - - - - -    - - -      _               ; // write 'd'
    _ =     ~   +                       (_ > 1)         ; // write '!'
    _ =     ~                           (_ > 1)         ; // write '\n'
}
```

Overall, not too bad. I wouldn't have done it, but that's because I wrote a Brainfuck to C# transpiler. Good work. :)

Comment: The indexer is a great idea, a good example for when they say to think outside the box.

Comment: @AdrianIftode It's one of those things where we're already abusing the snot out of the language, we *may as well* abuse it more. :)